# Bootstrap submenu highlighting stuck until next Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While hovering through dropdown menus, the color is changed to show the current item.

After clicking a submenu to open it, then clicking it again to close it, the highlighting from the hovering still remains until clicking again.

I need the menu highlight to disappear when it is clicked to close, and act as it would before being initially clicked, like the rest of the menu options.

[Here's a quick VIDEO of the problem](https://i.gyazo.com/4ceb167c3424767c09d3a77a73b1a674.mp4)

[LINK to index.html and style.css Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/387DpSN2)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: none;
}
```

When you click again to close submenu, css realize this is `focus`, so you can fix like this:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover:focus {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #CECECE;
}
```

Comment: Ran into a separate issue with this, however! When returning to the list, the red no longer appears over the options that were exited.

Comment: I just add pseudo-class `:hover:focus` , you can try again

Comment: Thanks a ton, Thanh! :)